# Highlighting modifications in a .tex file using Kile editor

Tags: highlighting, kile, changes

I am looking for any option of automatically highlighting the modified or added text (in pdf version after compilation) in my current `.tex` file using Kile editor. I know that there is a similar functionality in MS word but I am looking for it in Kile.

Comment: I use TeXstudio and after compiling the embedded viewer shows the pdf with the current line backgrounded. I don't know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) what you are after? You need to save manually the versions of the document your are working on (or using it with a [Version Control System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) like git, svn, hg, ...)

Comment: I've marked this as a dupe of the general 'track changes' question: if that's not right, please flag for reopening.